# How Low pressure moves across land

Tags: meteorology

I understand that low pressure systems (like hurricanes), can move across oceans since they are constantly fed by warm air from below.

But what is it that enables it to move across land? Especially in winter? From where is the warm air, needed to keep it rising, coming from?

Answer (score 3):

<sub>This will be an attempt to condense a very, very complicated description of earth's atmospheric system into a simple explanation. More than likely a failure will incur</sub>

First you have to realize that something being "warm" is relative. It would be better to use the word "warmer", since for convection to emerge it is enough that the air mass is warmer than its surroundings.

What basically keeps weather systems evolving and on the move is the rotation of the earth and the uneven solar radiation on surfaces.

The earth's rotation will "drag" along the air mass in contact with it. The amount of dragging is relative to both altitude and latitude, as they increase, the earth's rotational effect on air mass will become smaller and other effects such as [Coriolis effect](https://oceanservice.noaa.gov/education/tutorial_currents/media/supp_cur04b.html) will become more prevalent.

Variation in the sun's radiation longitudinally creates [convection currents](https://www.noaa.gov/jetstream/global/global-atmospheric-circulations), and the daily changes in surface temperature due to sun's path across the earths surface create moving convection zones.